# how to use <c:forEach > for loop String

Tags: foreach, jstl

if array data is

```
String sampdata[]= new String [22];

sampdata[0] ="a";,sampdata[1] ="b";
sampdata[2] ="c";,sampdata[3] ="d";
sampdata[4] ="e";,sampdata[5] ="f";
sampdata[6] ="g";,sampdata[7] ="h";
sampdata[8] ="i";,sampdata[9] ="j";
sampdata[10] ="k";,sampdata[11] ="l";
sampdata[12] ="m";,sampdata[13] ="n";sampdata[14] ="o";
sampdata[15] ="m";,sampdata[16] ="n";sampdata[174] ="o";
sampdata[18] ="m";,sampdata[19] ="n";sampdata[20] ="o";
sampdata[21] ="m";
```

and jsp use jstl foreach

```
<c:forEach var="list" items="${sampdata" begin="0" end="9" step="2" varStatus="status">
      <tr>
       <td>${list}</td>  //a
       <td>${list}</td>  //td : b
       <td></td>
     </tr>
    </c:forEach>
```

i mean

check this java array

```
for (int i=0 ; i<9;i +=2){
 System.out.println(i)
System.out.println(i+1) <- i want like this.
}
```

i want "td:b" view b.

how to  fix that?

"foreach" can use like that?

Comment: The right `}` missed in `items="${sampdata"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) on `loop` scoped variable with nested visibility that

> lets authors use the status object to obtain information about the iteration range, step, and current object.

```
<c:forEach items="${sampdata}" step="2" varStatus="loop">
  <c:out value="${sampdata[loop.index]}"/>
  <c:out value="${sampdata[loop.index+1]}"/>
</c:forEach>
```